# Total Return Swaps

Tags: price, swaps

I am trying to understand better Total Return Swaps and how they are priced (I have heard about projection-based and accrual-based models), can any body recommend good material to read (books, websites, exercises,...) or provide any useful information on the topic? Thank you

Comment: How do you define better? The underlying logic of a TRS is actually very simple. What is it that causes problems for you to understand?

Comment: This will probably be closed as "request for resource" which is off-topic. IF you have a specific question about TRS that would be better suited for this site. Also see this question: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/50907

Comment: I could reformulate my question by saying how do the projection-based method and the accrual-based method price swaps? What formulas do each method use